# Treated as zero Error while trying to place figure in a column

Tags: floats, errors, two-column

I am a latex newbie! I just wanted to place a figure in my two column document, I used multicol package but when I want to insert a figure in middle of text I get this Error:

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.

I used many ways, most of them were sophisticated and I did not figure out what they actually did but none of them were useful.
So I ask my question here and hope to get help from you guys! Thanks

by the way, This is part of my code I've problem with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[margin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,graphicx,float}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{fig3.png}}
\caption{
this is caption
}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: I don't see the "missing number treated as zero" when I compile your MWE. On the other hand, I do so the warning "Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols'
environment!."

Comment: not central to the question -- `\centering` does not take an argument.  it's essentially a "switch" that is in effect until the end of the current environment, which must end with a paragraph break for the effect to be reliable.  (the `figure` environment by default ends with a paragraph break, but has other problems here, as explained in another comment.)

Comment: I used same picture but a different caption(because previous caption has formulas and I thought maybe that's the problem) but this time the compilation process ends without significant warning except there was no figure in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Andrew, `multicols` does not allow floating environments.  As you are trying to force the figure to be exactly at this position with `[!h]` you may as well just use a `center` environment instead.  To put a caption on this, replace the `\caption` command by

```
\captionof{figure}{...}
```

The `\captionof` command is defined by the caption package which you are already loading.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,graphicx,float}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{center}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a.png}
    \captionof{figure}{this is caption}
  \end{center}
  \lipsum[2-8]
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```